# how to return more than 1 column with aggregation function in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate-functions

I have this table containing data from various hospitals about a group of medical conditions/procedures. Here is a snippet of it: [image: data]
[sample data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LvUvCua8lRCNylpU06bhnMKjLbTR3sv3Cky11VKW7R0/edit?usp=sharing)
**I am trying to create a list of each 13 `procedure/condition` and their `MAX` and `min` `risk_adjusted_mortality_rate` as well as the corresponding `hospital_full_name` for each max and min rate:**

this is what I am looking to achieve:
`procedure/condition , max_rar, max_hospital_full_name, min_rar, min_hospital_full_name`

I have tried calculating the `MAX` and `min` by grouping them on  `procedure/condition` and  using  this as a join with the current table to pull out the `max_hospital_full_name` and `min_hospital_full_name`:

```sql
         CREATE VIEW view1 as
     select [procedure/condition] , MAX(risk_adjusted_mortality_rate) as max_rar
      from imi..imi_2020
     group by [procedure/condition]
     
    
      select i20.[procedure/condition], hospital_full_name as max_hospital_full_name, county, view1.max_rar
      from imi..imi_2020 i20
      join view1
    on i20.risk_adjusted_mortality_rate= view1.max_rar
    AND i20.[procedure/condition]=view1.[procedure/condition]
```

result:
[image: results]

this is giving me the correct results and I plan to do the same to get the hospital corresponding to `min_rar` for all 13 `procedure/condition]` . However, I was hoping to get the results on a single table and not two. Can anybody suggest a better way?

Comment: Sample data and expected results, in a **consumable** format (*not* an image) will help us help you here.

Comment: you can use the window aggregate functions instead, they would allow you to get min / max but sitll access the original data. Like: select *, max(somefield) over(partition by someothergroupfield) from yourtable

Comment: @ThomA  I have added a link in the original question for the consumable sample data, the expected results and the results from the workaround. Please let me know if it helps!

Comment: @siggemannen I tired  with the windows function as well but it would deliver the result in a running form, one for each instance , so I would have multiple rows of each `procedure/condition` with same same `max` value listed out for them.

`select [procedure/condition], MAX(risk_adjusted_mortality_rate) over(partition by [procedure/condition])as max_rar,
  MIN(risk_adjusted_mortality_rate)over(partition by [procedure/condition]) as min_rar 
  from imi.dbo.imi_2020`

Comment: @VidushiKhanna, query from your last comment, with description how it failed your expectations, should be part of the question, not a comment. Please [edit] question and add it there (with appropriate formatting).

Comment: Ohh, now i get it, you want to find the *actual* hospital that has the largest and lowest risk_adjusted_mortality_rate.

Comment: If this your actual table,then it lack normalization due to which it may under perform.Also you can play with OSHPDID since it is int or fixed length data type.You can use good old group by and in the end result join with main table to get hospital name. It often perform better than multiple window function.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```sql
select  [Procedure/Condition]
,   max(case when maxrate = [Risk Adjuested Mortality Rate] then hospital end) as maxHospital
,   max(case when minrate = [Risk Adjuested Mortality Rate] then hospital end) as minHospital
,   maxrate, minrate
from (
    select  MAX([Risk Adjuested Mortality Rate]) over(partition by [Procedure/Condition]) as maxRate
    ,   MIN([Risk Adjuested Mortality Rate]) over(partition by [Procedure/Condition]) as minRate
    ,   *
    from (
        VALUES  (2020, N'Alameda', N'Kaiser Foundation Hospital – Oakland/Richmond', 106014326, N'Carotid Endarterectomy', 0, 0, 9, N'As Expected', -122.25791, 37.82402)
        ,   (2020, N'Alameda', N'Kaiser Foundation Hospital – Oakland/Richmond', 106014326, N'GI Hemorrhage', 1.6, 8, 334, N'As Expected', -122.25791, 37.82402)
        ,   (2020, N'Alameda', N'Kaiser Foundation Hospital – Oakland/Richmond', 106014326, N'Heart Failure', 2.4, 20, 756, N'As Expected', -122.25791, 37.82402)
        ,   (2020, N'Alameda', N'Kaiser Foundation Hospital – Oakland/Richmond', 106014326, N'Hip Fracture', 1.1, 2, 174, N'As Expected', -122.25791, 37.82402)
        ,   (2020, N'Alameda', N'Kaiser Foundation Hospital – Oakland/Richmond', 106014326, N'PCI', 2.6, 6, 189, N'As Expected', -122.25791, 37.82402)
        ,   (2020, N'Alameda', N'Kaiser Foundation Hospital – Oakland/Richmond', 106014326, N'Pancreatic Resection', 0, 0, 111, N'As Expected', -122.25791, 37.82402)
        ,   (2020, N'Alameda', N'Kaiser Foundation Hospital – Oakland/Richmond', 106014326, N'Pneumonia', 5, 29, 603, N'As Expected', -122.25791, 37.82402)
        ,   (2020, N'Alameda', N'Stanford Health Care – ValleyCare', 106014050, N'Carotid Endarterectomy', 0, 0, 15, N'As Expected', -121.88095, 37.69206)
        ,   (2020, N'Alameda', N'Stanford Health Care – ValleyCare', 106014050, N'GI Hemorrhage', 1.5, 3, 122, N'As Expected', -121.88095, 37.69206)
        ,   (2020, N'Alameda', N'Stanford Health Care – ValleyCare', 106014050, N'Heart Failure', 2.2, 9, 314, N'As Expected', -121.88095, 37.69206)
        ,   (2020, N'Alameda', N'Stanford Health Care – ValleyCare', 106014050, N'Hip Fracture', 2.1, 2, 81, N'As Expected', -121.88095, 37.69206)
        ,   (2020, N'Alameda', N'Stanford Health Care – ValleyCare', 106014050, N'PCI', 4.6, 4, 105, N'As Expected', -121.88095, 37.69206)
        ,   (2020, N'Butte', N'Oroville Hospital', 106040937, N'AMI', 3.9, 2, 54, N'As Expected', -121.5428, 39.50485)
        ,   (2020, N'Butte', N'Oroville Hospital', 106040937, N'Acute Stroke', 10.4, 13, 183, N'As Expected', -121.5428, 39.50485)
        ,   (2020, N'Butte', N'Oroville Hospital', 106040937, N'Acute Stroke Hemorrhagic', 21.6, 2, 7, N'As Expected', -121.5428, 39.50485)
        ,   (2020, N'Butte', N'Oroville Hospital', 106040937, N'Acute Stroke Ischemic', 5.5, 9, 173, N'As Expected', -121.5428, 39.50485)
        ,   (2020, N'Butte', N'Oroville Hospital', 106040937, N'Acute Stroke Subarachnoid', 45.6, 2, 3, N'As Expected', -121.5428, 39.50485)
        ,   (2020, N'Butte', N'Oroville Hospital', 106040937, N'Carotid Endarterectomy', 0, 0, 10, N'As Expected', -121.5428, 39.50485)
        ,   (2020, N'Butte', N'Oroville Hospital', 106040937, N'GI Hemorrhage', 1.2, 3, 213, N'As Expected', -121.5428, 39.50485)
        ,   (2020, N'Butte', N'Oroville Hospital', 106040937, N'Heart Failure', 0.9, 3, 445, N'Better', -121.5428, 39.50485)
        ,   (2020, N'Butte', N'Oroville Hospital', 106040937, N'Hip Fracture', 1.1, 1, 65, N'As Expected', -121.5428, 39.50485)
        ,   (2020, N'Butte', N'Oroville Hospital', 106040937, N'PCI', 0, 0, 3, N'As Expected', -121.5428, 39.50485)
        ,   (2020, N'Butte', N'Oroville Hospital', 106040937, N'Pancreatic Resection', NULL, NULL, NULL, N'', -121.5428, 39.50485)
        ,   (2020, N'Butte', N'Oroville Hospital', 106040937, N'Pneumonia', 4.4, 27, 942, N'Better', -121.5428, 39.50485)
        ,   (2020, N'Butte', N'Enloe Medical Center – Esplanade', 106040962, N'AAA Repair Endo Unruptured', 11.5, 1, 14, N'As Expected', -121.84918, 39.74226)
        ,   (2020, N'Butte', N'Enloe Medical Center – Esplanade', 106040962, N'AAA Repair Open Unruptured', 0, 0, 4, N'As Expected', -121.84918, 39.74226)
        ,   (2020, N'Butte', N'Enloe Medical Center – Esplanade', 106040962, N'AMI', 5.7, 22, 376, N'As Expected', -121.84918, 39.74226)
        ,   (2020, N'Butte', N'Enloe Medical Center – Esplanade', 106040962, N'Acute Stroke', 13.6, 42, 383, N'Worse', -121.84918, 39.74226)
        ,   (2020, N'Butte', N'Enloe Medical Center – Esplanade', 106040962, N'Acute Stroke Hemorrhagic', 37.4, 21, 66, N'Worse', -121.84918, 39.74226)
        ,   (2020, N'Butte', N'Enloe Medical Center – Esplanade', 106040962, N'Acute Stroke Ischemic', 6.3, 17, 311, N'As Expected', -121.84918, 39.74226)
        ,   (2020, N'Butte', N'Enloe Medical Center – Esplanade', 106040962, N'Acute Stroke Subarachnoid', 38.2, 4, 6, N'As Expected', -121.84918, 39.74226)
        ,   (2020, N'Butte', N'Enloe Medical Center – Esplanade', 106040962, N'Carotid Endarterectomy', 0, 0, 53, N'As Expected', -121.84918, 39.74226)
        ,   (2020, N'Butte', N'Enloe Medical Center – Esplanade', 106040962, N'GI Hemorrhage', 3.5, 10, 413, N'As Expected', -121.84918, 39.74226)
        ,   (2020, N'Butte', N'Enloe Medical Center – Esplanade', 106040962, N'Heart Failure', 3.3, 27, 843, N'As Expected', -121.84918, 39.74226)
        ,   (2020, N'Butte', N'Enloe Medical Center – Esplanade', 106040962, N'Hip Fracture', 0, 0, 212, N'As Expected', -121.84918, 39.74226)
        ,   (2020, N'Butte', N'Enloe Medical Center – Esplanade', 106040962, N'PCI', 3.3, 11, 307, N'As Expected', -121.84918, 39.74226)
        ,   (2020, N'Butte', N'Enloe Medical Center – Esplanade', 106040962, N'Pancreatic Resection', NULL, 0, 13, N'As Expected', -121.84918, 39.74226)
        ,   (2020, N'Butte', N'Enloe Medical Center – Esplanade', 106040962, N'Pneumonia', 7.5, 49, 745, N'As Expected', -121.84918, 39.74226)
    ) t (YEAR,COUNTY,HOSPITAL,OSHPDID,[Procedure/Condition],[Risk Adjuested Mortality Rate],[# of Deaths],[# of Cases],[Hospital Ratings],LONGITUDE,LATITUDE)
    ) x
group by [Procedure/Condition], maxRate, minRate
```

First you find out the max / min rates per condition but still keep rest of the data, then you compare each hospital's rate with the max rate, and if it matches, then you take the hospital name and do a group by.

Since case when condition doesn't have ELSE, the non-matching hospitals become NULL values, which should never count toward MAX.

There's one problem left, that is the NULL values in the rates. Since null can never be equal anything else, i would suggest replacing null values with something else, maybe 0, but i don't know your data as you do.

Comment: this worked like a charm!
However, I was of a believe that `MIN` and `MAX` took `numeric` inputs. I have noticed in your solution that the `MIN` and `MAX` in the outer query are essentially taking a `string` input via the case statement. Besides the obvious advantage of not putting the `maxHospital` and `minHospital` in the `group by` clause I was wondering how it was looking for a `max` string from a complete column . I also tried it on a group of strings and it worked.
could you please explain this functioning briefly, as well?

Comment: MAX works on strings by comparing them collation-wise. For example: MAX of 'a' and 'b' will in general return 'b'. MAX of 'abc' and 'b' will also return 'b' because it compares character by character and first character of b is ahead of first character of abc!

Comment: MAX of null and 'a' will return 'a' because NULL is never max (unless all values are NULL).  The trick here is the CASE WHEN. CASE WHEN somecondition THEN 'a' END leaves out the ELSE part, which means that if somecondition is false, NULL is returned, which will never be MAX. This allows us to pick up the matching hospital name because only it will match against the condition. If two hospital would have same mortality rate, it will then have to compare the hospitals names, but that's life :)

Comment: thank you for explanation. Since you are a bit aware of the dataset now, could you please have a look at the below as well: 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76243244/find-out-the-count-of-each-subcategory-for-each-of-the-various-categories-in-sql

Comment: Sure, answered there too :D